# XmlDocument.Save() String / Timestamp as part of the file name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am calling the XmlDocument.Save() method and attempting to append the String value below to my file name. The method call throws an error and is complaining about the format.

Any help would be appreciated! \m/ \m/

```
Dim strTimestamp As String = "2017-08-30T08:44:40-05:00"
XmlDocument.Save("C:\Temp\FileName_" & strTimestamp & ".xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is obviously the special characters in the file name so I am going to use the following DateTime format.

```
Dim strTimestamp As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--hh-mm-ss").
```

Comment: The colon is not valid in a filename. I think `yyyy-MM-ddTHHmmss` should work and be ISO8601-compliant